# Sharing VisualStateGroups between styles

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, visualstategroup

I have the following xaml

```
<Style x:Key="GridStyle" TargetType="Grid">
    <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
        <Setter.Value>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ControlColour}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ButtonCLickedBackground}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But I get VisualStateGroups type must be assigned to IList
but I need it to be shared across multiple templates that have the same visualStateGroup then differ so was trying to make the VisualStateGroup into a style I can apply to the grids I use in the button templates.

```
 <Setter Property="Template">
       <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ButtonBase">
                <Grid Style="{StaticResource GridStyle}" Background="Transparent">
                    <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}" >
                    <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Rectangle Width="17" Height="5"  Fill="{Binding ElementName=ContentContainer, Path=Foreground}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ContentControl>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

At last I can't seem to work it out can anyone help or will I just have to copy paste the VisualStateGroup across all the different button styles I need?

Answer (score 1):

> But I get VisualStateGroups type must be assigned to IList but I need it to be shared across multiple templates that have the same visualStateGroup then differ so was trying to make the VisualStateGroup into a style I can apply to the grids I use in the button templates.

The `VisualStateGroups` is attached property, you could not set it like dependency property in the `Grid` Style. If you want to use it in the button templates. You could edit Button Xaml Style directly like following.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Blue" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundPressed}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushPressed}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundDisabled}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground"
                BorderBrush="OldLace" BorderThickness="5" Background="White">
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

**Usage**

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" Content="ClickME" />
```